# How to validate access token provided by simle_oauth in custom controller?

Tags: drupal, oauth, drupal-9, simple-oauth2

In my drupal 9 project I have installed simple_oauth module and I have configured it.

By accessing /oauth/token, I am able to generate access token and refresh token successfully.

But, I need to validate the access token in my custom controller. For example,

I have a controller and route (/api/user-profile) which should retrieve the current logged in user's profile by using the access token.

Kindly help!